# "Undefined offset" in PHP array after using explode(...)

Tags: php

Can u tell me why show me tons of notice ?

I am new in php and don't understand where is my mistake, notices from line:

```
<td>'.$columns[1].'</td>
```

To line:

```
$sum+=$columns[2];
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
         if(file_exists('data.txt'))
         {
             $result= file('data.txt');
             $sum='0';

             foreach($result as $value)
             {

                 $columns=explode('-', $value);

                 echo  '<tr>
                             <td>'.$columns[0].'</td>
                             <td>'.$columns[1].'</td>
                             <td>'.$columns[2].'</td>
                             <td>'.$kinds[trim($columns[3])].'</td>
                        </tr>';
                 $sum+=$columns[2];

             }
             echo '<tr>
                <td>--</td>
                <td>--</td>
                <td>' . $sum . ' </td>
                <td>--</td>
            </tr>'; 


         }             
         ?>
```

I am new in php and don't understand where is my mistake :( notices from line

```
<td>'.$columns[1].'</td>
```

to line

```
$sum+=$columns[2];
```

Here are the notices:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31 
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 33
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 29
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 30
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31
```

Comment: Can you show us the output (with notices)?

Comment: Please share the notices you are getting.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31

Comment: I agree with @FritsvanCampen but my bet is that you're not exploding data correctly.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HomeworkOne\index.php on line 33

Comment: Or the txt file is not what you think it is.

Comment: Also, i've retitled your question to match the new informations. Please try to find more meaningful titles in the future

Comment: Try to use the condition if(isset($columns[2])) { where ever applicable.

Comment: @VineeshPoduval this will throw an undefined offset error too.

Comment: @DanFromGermany it won't raise notice, even something like this won't:  `isset($undefined_variable[0][5][10][11])`. isset is not a function.

Comment: Add contents of the txt file.

Answer (score 2):

You are using uninitialized variables.
`$columns[1]`, `$columns[2]` and `$columns[3]` are not getting values
Please try this corrected code:

```
<?php
if(file_exists('data.txt'))
{
    $result= file('data.txt');
    $sum='0';

    foreach($result as $value)
    {

        $columns=explode('-', $value);
        $kindsDisplay = (isset($columns[3]) && ! empty($kinds[trim($columns[3])])) ? $kinds[trim($columns[3])] : '';
        $one = isset($columns[1]) ? $columns[1] : '';
        $two = isset($columns[2]) ? $columns[2] : '';
        $sum+= isset($columns[2]) ? $columns[2] : 0;

        echo  '<tr>
                   <td>'.$columns[0].'</td>
                   <td>'.$columns[1].'</td>
                   <td>'.$columns[2].'</td>
                   <td>'.$kindsDisplay.'</td>
               </tr>';

    }

    echo '<tr>
              <td>--</td>
              <td>--</td>
              <td>' . $sum . ' </td>
              <td>--</td>
          </tr>'; 

} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an undefined offset:

```
$array[0] = "test1";
$array[1] = "test2";

echo $array[3];
```

You are better off using objects or arrays where you know whats inside.

To get rid use if's:

```
$array[0] = "test1";
$array[1] = "test2";

if (array_key_exists(3, $array)) {
    echo $array[3];
}
```

The problem in your case:

```
$columns = explode('-', $value);
```

The data you grep from the textfile is not 100% the format you expect, for example:

```
aaaaa-bbbbbb-cccccc-ddddddd
aaaaa--cccccc-dddddd
aaaaa-ddddd
```

This means, you need to verify tha data you read is VALID and in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider: a blank line at the end of the file could cause this if it only happens once (not each line).

If you want to have default values in case your data is missing seperators you can add

```
$columns = $columns + array('default_for_key0', 'default1', 'default2', 'default3');
```

after `explode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You read every line of the data file. When you have a blank line you have no data in your `$result`.

Then you try to explode on an empty string and `columns[0]` is not set.

Try to check if the array is not empty perhaps with

```
if(count($columns) > 2) {

}
```

or check wheather the array is set.

```
if(isset($columns[0])) {

}
```

otherwise you can fill the array with default data.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is probably not as sane as you think.

```
$columns=explode('-', "abc");
$columns[0]; // "abc";
$columns[1]; // gives: Undefined offset 1
```

Either ensure your data is what you expect, or explicitly try to find error cases, like a line with no `-`.

You can do `count($columns)` to find out how many columns there are.

---

Be very wary of constructions like:

```
$kinds[trim($columns[3])]
```

You have 2 possible undefined offsets here. `$columns[3]` and `$kinds[#index#]` can both be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and you will see if you have 4 columns every time:

```
<?php
if (file_exists('data.txt')) {
    $result= file('data.txt');
    $sum=0;

    foreach($result as $value) {
        $columns=explode('-', $value);
        echo  '<tr>';
        foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
            echo '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
            if ($key == 2) $sum += $column;
        }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>--</td><td>--</td><td>'.$sum.'</td><td>--</td></tr>'; 
}             
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to set $kinds as array.
Secondly, check array keys before you use in the program else it will throw errors like below: http://d.pr/i/GzVk

Check the revised code, I Hope this will helpful for you.

```
<?php
if(file_exists('data.txt'))
{
$result= file('data.txt');
$sum='0';
$kinds = array();

foreach($result as $value)
{

$columns=explode('-', $value);

if(array_key_exists($columns[0], $columns)) {
echo '<td>'.$columns[0].'</td>';
}
if(isset($columns[1]) && array_key_exists($columns[1], $columns)) {
echo '<td>'.$columns[1].'</td>';
}

if(isset($columns[2]) && array_key_exists($columns[2], $columns)) {
echo '<td>'.$columns[2].'</td>';
$sum+=$columns[2];
}

if(isset($columns[3]) && array_key_exists($columns[3], $columns)) {
echo '<td>'.$kinds[trim($columns[3])].'</td>';
}

echo      '</tr>';


}
echo '<tr>
<td>--</td>
<td>--</td>
<td>' . $sum . ' </td>
<td>--</td>
</tr>';


}
?>
```